# How to copy the background view of the actual Navigation Bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I copy the actual UINagivationBar background appearance? I would like to have the exact background appearance to use on another view.

Comment: do you mean the gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct way to access the gradient background of the UINavigationBar. You can, however, play around with mockup versions of the background [here](http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-5-gui-psd-iphone-4s/) and create your own version using Photoshop.